# Multiple Advertisers in Login With Amazon

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

we currently building an app, the goal is to provide our customers who are amazon advertisers with a customized dashboard to manage their own Amazon data, we create LWA by following these steps https://advertising.amazon.com/API/docs/en-us/setting-up/step-1-create-lwa-app. So far we successfully onboarded a new advertiser by authorizing our app by the advertiser through LWA and we are able to pull the advertiser's data like Sponsored Products, Sponsored Videos and Sponsored Display using the advertiser profileID. We are planning to integrate hundred of advertisers into our app. We tried to onboard a second advertiser before we push our app in production, however, we are stuck in getting the new advertiser's profileID.Actually the authorization through LWA was successful for this second advertiser, the amazon response contains the advertiser's information like Name, customerId, Primary_email which we then saved into our own database. The /profiles endpoint in Advertising API contains only the profileId of the first advertiser we previously onboarded. We are expecting tru profile's in /profiles API since we already onboarderd twi advertisers. My question is, why we can't get the profileID for the second advertiser we onboarded? It seems that the authorization through LWA was successful but it doesn't authorized our app to have access to the new advertiser's data because the profileID was not available in /profiles endpoint.

According to the support engineer, it is not possible to have multiple advertisers to authorize our app tru LWA.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Regards

Comment: You need to use the new (2nd) client_id that is generated after successfully authenticating with LWA- along with the new access/refresh token. You either databased the wrong info, or are requesting /profiles with the wrong client's info.

Comment: hi @mr_mooo_cow, how do you mean client_id? are you refering to customerID? Also when an advertiser authorize our app using LWA, we can only see cusotmer info and access_token but no refresh token

Comment: You use the access token(expires 60m) to get a refresh token the very first time and in future instances you use the refresh token (which does not expire) to obtain a new access token to make API calls. But your problem is you are using the wrong token associated with your client#1's credentials. So you should have 2 distinct refresh tokens saved after completing the LWA process.

Comment: Keep in mind if you have a script running >60m you should be handling the response code 'UNAUTHORIZED' to handle generating a new access token since they expire.

Comment: thanks @mr_mooo_cow. I found out that refresh token doesnt comes when using javascript sdk for security reasons.I will rewrite my lwa to process in server side